# Latency spikes in android when writting to file

Tags: android, performance, testing, file-io, latency

I am running some performance tests and see some spikes in my tests results.
This is the code I use to measure the time of the writing to file.

```
public class Test extends AndroidTestCase {

private DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
private final Boolean isInternal = true;

public void testWrite() {
    Thread thread = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            File dummy_file = createFile("dummy2", true);
            File file = createFile("normal_write", isInternal);
            for (int i = 0; i < 12500; i++) {
                long start = System.nanoTime();
                write(dummy_file, String.valueOf(i));
                long stop = System.nanoTime();
                double mSec = ((double) (stop - start) / 1000000.0);
                write(file, decimalFormat.format(mSec));
            }
        }
    };

    thread.start();

    try {
        thread.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public File createFile(String fileName, Boolean isInternal) {
    deleteFile(fileName, isInternal);
    try {
        String file_path = "";
        if(isInternal == true) {
            file_path = getContext().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + fileName + ".dat";
        } else {
            file_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + fileName + ".dat";
        }
        File file = new File(file_path);
        file.createNewFile();
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile(), true);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        bw.write("##;##\n" +
                "@LiveGraph demo file.\n" +
                "Time");
        bw.newLine();
        bw.close();
        return file;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

public void deleteFile(String fileName, Boolean isInternal) {
    String file_path = "";
    if ( isInternal == true) {
        file_path = getContext().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + fileName + ".dat";
    } else {
        file_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + fileName + ".dat";
    }
    File file = new File(file_path);
    file.delete();
}

public void write(File file, String content) {
    try {
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile(), true);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        bw.write(content);
        bw.newLine();
        bw.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Mostly the time it takes to write is ~0.1-0.2ms but there are spikes which takes 10+ ms and can not figure out what the cause of this is. I can not link the graph here right now as I am a new user here.

I am really stuck with this any ideas?.

This is part of the time measurements.

0.16
0.16
0.17
0.15
0.15
2.5
0.17
0.16
0.16
0.16
0.15
0.17
0.17
0.17
0.19
0.19
0.17
0.2
0
0
4.79
0.24
0.23
0.28
0.23
0.28
0.03
0
11.23
0.16
0.15
0.18
0.16
0.16
0.17
0.16
5.84

Answer (score 0):

It may be related to Android's storage access specifics:

> Background on disks on phones Wait, what’s wrong with hitting the
>   disk? Android devices are all running flash memory, right? That’s like
>   a super-fast SSD with no moving parts? I shouldn’t have to care?
>   Unfortunately, you do.
>
> You can’t depend on the flash components or filesystems used in most
>   Android devices to be consistently fast. The YAFFS filesystem used on
>   many Android devices, for instance, has a global lock around all its
>   operations. Only one disk operation can be in-flight across the entire
>   device. Even a simple “stat” operation can take quite a while if you
>   are unlucky. Other devices with more traditional block device-based
>   filesystems still occasionally suffer when the block rotation layer
>   decides to garbage collect and do some slow internal flash erase
>   operations. (For some good geeky background reading, see
>   lwn.net/Articles/353411)
>
> The take-away is that the “disk” (or filesystem) on mobile devices is
>   usually fast, but the 90th percentile latencies are often quite poor.
>   Also, most filesystems slow down quite a bit as they get more full.
>   (See slides from Google I/O Zippy Android apps talk, linked off
>   code.google.com/p/zippy-android)

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/12/new-gingerbread-api-strictmode.html

Comment: wouldn't this only cover the scenario of running on a real device? I am doing this on an emulator and my laptop have only a normal hard drive.

Comment: Maybe garbage collecting? You are creating quite a lot of objects and GC can take some CPU time, which is expensive on the emulator. Check the logcat, it should contain info about GC.

If it's not the case, run the test on "standard" VM and compare the results - maybe it's your laptop's FS/OS issue.

Comment: Since java nanotime is used could it be that it is the cause to the problem?

Comment: What about GC? Have you checked it?

Comment: Yes i have checked if GC was the cause and it does't seem so, since there is spikes without it being ran.

Comment: Beside the high spikes there are times that are 0 as well

Comment: It seems the timer freezes which causes some of the spikes that can be fixed but there are jumps in the timer sometimes as well which is weird.